# A QR code which opens a picture from a page in the Facebook app

Tags: facebook, qr-code

I am looking to create a  QR code which will open this picture in the users app, so that the user can like the picture and hopefully help my band to win an award :-)

http://www.facebook.com/highvoltageawards/photos/a.768979109875764.1073741832.710487739058235/761209933986015/

I have tried various qr readers, replaced "http://www.facebook.com/highvoltageawards/" with "fb://profile/710487739058235/" and all kinds of combinations.

Is this even possible?

Best, Astrid

Answer (score 0):

You can try this QR Code as generated from QR Code Generator by Aspose.BarCode for Java. http://goo.gl/ENJjzw

Please download image from this link: http://bit.ly/1ELPRbt

Comment: That is no good. It opens in a browser, and then the user has to log in. Upon logging in, the user is redirected to the page on which the photo is, and then he has to find the photo himself. Sorry, that is not what I wanted. I want a QR code that opens the photo in the users app so that he can click the "Like" button.